# Double spacing a file using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I was going through the awk and found the below two commands for double spacing a file.

Can someone please explain how these commands actually work ?

```
awk '1;{print ""}' filename

awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n\n"};1' filename
```

Thanks

Comment: do the two statements actually do what you want? what do you mean double space? If your original file is 100Kb, after running this, do you have 200kb file? This two statements do nothing more than change single line break into two.

Comment: The 2nd command can be written as `awk -v ORS="\n\n" 1 filename` to exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example uses two common awk shortcuts: `1` is just a pattern that is always true, so the default action, which is "print the line", is executed for every line. Then, there is a rule with an empty pattern (which is also always true, but you can't omit both pattern and action), which in its action just prints an empty line.

Your second example changes the **O**utput **R**ecord **S**eparator, which is usually just a single end-of-line, to be two, so that just copying every line will be enough. (BEGIN rules are executed before the input file is read.)